# How do I code that an optional parameter outside the temporary view has mutated into a steady one?

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

I have to transform a bunch of pretty generic IIFE JavaScript modules to TypeScript.
Some root modules can hold a lot of optional child modules, witch also holds optional modules and params.
This leeds to an overwelming of if-exist-conditions. Even in the is-true branches, the existence of what has already been established must continue to be checked.
How do I code that an optional parameter outside the temporary view has mutated into a steady one?

This is an exemplary IIFE JavaScript modules

```
{
    var generic = generic || {};
    generic.example = {
        get: function(str) {
            return generic.example.helper.deepGetter(str);
        },
        set: function(str) {
            return generic.example.helper.deepSetter(str);
        },
        helper: {
            deepGetter(str) {
                // return nested value;
            },
            deepSetter(str, value) {
                // set nested value;
            },
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how my TypeScript dilemma looks

```
declare interface OptionA {}
declare interface OptionB {}
declare interface OptionC {}
declare interface OptionD {
    getWithPointer(param: string): any | void,
    getOutOfScope(param: string): any | void,
    getNotSmart(param: string): any | void,
    helper: Helper
}

declare interface Helper {
    deepGetter(param: string): any | void,
    deepSetter(param: string, value: any): void
}

declare interface Generic {
    possible?: OptionA,
    maybe?: OptionB,
    eventually?: OptionC,
    example?: OptionD
}

declare var generic: Generic;

{
    var generic = generic || {};
    generic.example = {
        getWithPointer: function(str) {
            // fails because (property) Generic.example?: OptionD | undefined
            // Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
            return generic.example.helper.deepGetter(str);
        },
        getOutOfScope: function(str) {
            // Does not work with asynchronous callback nesting.
            return this.helper.deepGetter(str);
        },
        getNotSmart: function(str) {
            // It works, but it's really stupid and leads to unreadable spaghetti code.
            // Especially when a lot of conditions have to be processed in the helper.
            if (generic.example && generic.example.helper) {
                return generic.example.helper.deepGetter(str);
            } 
        },
        helper: {
            deepGetter(str) {
                return 'deep nested value';
            },
            deepSetter(str, value) {
                // set deep nested value;
            },
        }
    }
}
```

I have always to type `if (generic.example ...` inside of `generic.example = {}` and for all nested objects.

This is, what i would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up the documentation helps...
My problem can be easily solved by assertions.

```
declare interface Example {
    get(param: string): any | void,
    set(param: string, value: any): void,
    helper: Helper
}

declare interface Helper {
    deepGetter(param: string): any | void,
    deepSetter(param: string, value: any): void
}

declare interface Generic {
    example?: Example
}

declare var generic: Generic;

{
    var generic = generic || {};
    generic.example = {
        get: function(str: string) {
            const self = <Example>generic.example;
            return self.helper.deepGetter(str);
        },
        set: function(str: string, value: any) {
            const self = <Example>generic.example;
            self.helper.deepSetter(str, value);
        },
        helper: {
            deepGetter(str: string) {
                return 'deep nested value';
            },
            deepSetter(str: string, value: any) {
                // set deep nested value;
            },
        }
    }
}
```